# Virtualbox installation error in kali linux

Tags: systemd, kali-linux, virtualbox, kernel-modules, dkms

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools dkms libgsoap-2.8.104 liblzf1 libvncserver1 linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86
  linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64 linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-5.10
  virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
  vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools dkms libgsoap-2.8.104 liblzf1 libvncserver1 linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86
  linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64 linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-5.10
  virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 821 not upgraded.
Need to get 57.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 240 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dctrl-tools amd64 2.24-3+b1 [104 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 dkms all 2.8.4-3 [78.2 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libgsoap-2.8.104 amd64 2.8.104-3 [284 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 liblzf1 amd64 3.6-3 [10.2 kB]                        
Get:5 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libvncserver1 amd64 0.9.13+dfsg-2 [233 kB]           
Get:6 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86 amd64 5.10.40-1kali1 [1,040 kB]
Get:7 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common all 5.10.40-1kali1 [9,537 kB]
Get:8 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-kbuild-5.10 amd64 5.10.40-1kali1 [1,283 kB]    
Get:9 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64 amd64 5.10.40-1kali1 [1,562 kB]
Get:10 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 linux-headers-amd64 amd64 5.10.40-1kali1 [1,148 B]  
Get:11 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 virtualbox-dkms amd64 6.1.22-dfsg-1 [724 kB]     
Get:12 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 virtualbox amd64 6.1.22-dfsg-1 [21.3 MB]         
Get:13 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 virtualbox-qt amd64 6.1.22-dfsg-1 [21.5 MB]      
Fetched 57.7 MB in 2min 16s (423 kB/s)                                                                           
Selecting previously unselected package dctrl-tools.
(Reading database ... 426977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-dctrl-tools_2.24-3+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dctrl-tools (2.24-3+b1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../01-dkms_2.8.4-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.4-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap-2.8.104:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgsoap-2.8.104_2.8.104-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgsoap-2.8.104:amd64 (2.8.104-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblzf1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-liblzf1_3.6-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblzf1:amd64 (3.6-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvncserver1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libvncserver1_0.9.13+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.13+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86.
Preparing to unpack .../05-linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86_5.10.40-1kali1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common.
Preparing to unpack .../06-linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common_5.10.40-1kali1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-kbuild-5.10.
Preparing to unpack .../07-linux-kbuild-5.10_5.10.40-1kali1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-kbuild-5.10 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64_5.10.40-1kali1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-linux-headers-amd64_5.10.40-1kali1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-amd64 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../10-virtualbox-dkms_6.1.22-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (6.1.22-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../11-virtualbox_6.1.22-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (6.1.22-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../12-virtualbox-qt_6.1.22-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (6.1.22-dfsg-1) ...
Setting up linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-common (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Setting up libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.13+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up liblzf1:amd64 (3.6-3) ...
Setting up libgsoap-2.8.104:amd64 (2.8.104-3) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-5.10 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Setting up dctrl-tools (2.24-3+b1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.10.0-kali8-amd64:.
Setting up dkms (2.8.4-3) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.22-dfsg-1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.22 DKMS files...
Building for 5.10.0-kali3-amd64
Module build for kernel 5.10.0-kali3-amd64 was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up linux-headers-amd64 (5.10.40-1kali1) ...
Setting up virtualbox (6.1.22-dfsg-1) ...
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-06-26 00:03:38 IST; 21ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 10512 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 40ms

Jun 26 00:03:38 kali systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jun 26 00:03:38 kali virtualbox[10512]: Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...No suitable module for running kernel 
found ...
Jun 26 00:03:38 kali virtualbox[10522]:  failed!
Jun 26 00:03:38 kali virtualbox[10523]:  failed!
Jun 26 00:03:38 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 26 00:03:38 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 26 00:03:38 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (6.1.22-dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.48) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.68) ...
Processing triggers for kali-menu (2021.1.4) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
```

Comment: Read the error message. It's failing to build the kernel module because you didn't install the headers for your current kernel, and without the kernel module it can't set up the software.

Comment: @Shadur Which package should OP install to solve this?  I see that `linux-headers-5.10.0-kali8-amd64` was unpacked earlier in the log.

Comment: @stewart Again, from looking at the apt log, dkms is failing to build the module for the current kernel saying `Module build for kernel 5.10.0-kali3-amd64 was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.`

Comment: @Shadur How am i supposed to install the headers

Comment: If you have to ask these kinds of questions, then *please* consider using something other than Kali Linux as a desktop OS.